# SQLite Force printing headers even if result set is empty

Tags: sql, sqlite

When the query returns an empty result the headers are not printed. Is there a way to force printing the headers in any case?

For example in this case, when a result **is not** empty the `.headers` pragma indeed prints to the `.output` file, but in cases where the query returns an empty result the file is empty (no headers). I would still like in the empty corner case to print the headers to the file since the resulting output file is fead to other systems and they rely on those headers. Is it possible to force the headers in the resulting file?

```
-- setup to provide headers and to output as csv
.headers on
.mode csv
-- Attaching the databases
attach '/tmp/1.db' as existingdb;
attach '/tmp/2.db' as newdb;
-- Deletions query
.output /tmp/test/res/deletes.csv
SELECT a.sku AS "old:sku" , a.c1 AS "old:c1" , a.c2 AS "old:c2"  FROM existingdb.products AS a LEFT JOIN newdb.products AS b on a.sku = b.sku WHERE b.sku IS NULL;
```

Another trivial example:

```
sqlite> .tables
sqlite> create table test(a,b,c);
sqlite> select * from test;
sqlite>
sqlite> insert into test values (1,2,3);
sqlite> select * from test;
1|2|3
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> select * from test;
a|b|c <<< the headers are printed
1|2|3
sqlite> select * from test where a = 2;
sqlite> result is empy - no headers are printed!
```

Comment: sqlite != MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sqlite3` command-line shell does not print the headers until it receives the first result row.

You'd have to modify the shell's source code, or use your own tool.

Comment: Wonder why this was the design decision since i am explicitly requesting them